# Closest pair SPOJ logN time wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, closest

I am trying to solve this problem. http://www.spoj.com/problems/CLOPPAIR/
My main idea is to divide coordinates into parts where in the same part all dots will have same x. Sort all coordinates by x and y. 
When will I check which dots is the closest to Ni I will compare it with higher y same x and lower y and same x. I will also try to search in previous part of x coordinate and search them with binary search and I will also search the next part of x coordinate.
But I allways get wrong answer. Can anyone tell me what is wrong. Code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,int>par;
typedef long long int ll;
par niz[55000];
map<ll,ll>mapa2;
map<par,ll>mapa;
map<ll,ll>mapa3;
vector<par>V[55000];
ll a,b,c,d,e,f;
double euk=1561561616;
ll toc=0,toc2=0;
ll pos1=1,pos2;
void binary(ll pos,ll end)
{
     if(pos<pos1-1)
     {

      ll tockay=V[pos][end].second;
      ll low=0;
      ll high=V[pos+1].size();
      ll midd=0;
      while(low<=high)
      {
         midd=(low+high)/2;
         if(V[pos+1][midd].second>tockay)high=midd-1;
         else low=midd+1;
      }
      if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd].second)))
      {
        euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd].second));
        toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
        toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos+1][midd].first,V[pos+1][midd].second)];
      }
      if(midd-1>=0)
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-1].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-1].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos+1][midd-1].first,V[pos+1][midd-1].second)];
         } 
      }
      if(midd-2>=0)
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-2].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd-2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd-2].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos+1][midd-2].first,V[pos+1][midd-2].second)];
         } 
      }
      if(midd+1<V[pos+1].size())
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+1].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+1].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos+1][midd+1].first,V[pos+1][midd+1].second)];
         } 
      } 
      if(midd+2<V[pos+1].size())
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+2].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos+1][midd+2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos+1][midd+2].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos+1][midd+2].first,V[pos+1][midd+2].second)];
         } 
      }                      
     }
     //prllf("hhkhj %d\n",pos);
     if(pos!=1)
     {

      ll tockay=V[pos][end].second;
      ll low=0;
      ll high=V[pos-1].size();
      ll midd=0;
      while(low<=high)
      {
         midd=(low+high)/2;
         if(V[pos-1][midd].second>tockay)high=midd-1;
         else low=midd+1;
      }
      if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd].second)))
      {
        euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd].second));
        toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
        toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos-1][midd].first,V[pos-1][midd].second)];
      }
      if(midd-1>=0)
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-1].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-1].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos-1][midd-1].first,V[pos-1][midd-1].second)];
         } 
      }
      if(midd-2>=0)
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-2].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd-2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd-2].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos-1][midd-2].first,V[pos-1][midd-2].second)];
         } 
      }
      if(midd+1<V[pos-1].size())
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+1].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+1].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+1].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+1].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+1].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos-1][midd+1].first,V[pos-1][midd+1].second)];
         } 
      }
      if(midd+2<V[pos+1].size())
      {
         if(euk>sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+2].second)))
         {
          euk=sqrt((V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+2].first)*(V[pos][end].first-V[pos-1][midd+2].first)+(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+2].second)*(V[pos][end].second-V[pos-1][midd+2].second));
          toc=mapa[make_pair(V[pos][end].first,V[pos][end].second)];
          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[pos-1][midd+2].first,V[pos-1][midd+2].second)];
         } 
      }
     }
}  
int main()
{
    scanf("%llu",&a);
    for(ll i=0;i<a;++i)
    {
            scanf("%llu%llu",&b,&c);
            niz[i]=make_pair(b,c);
            mapa[make_pair(b,c)]=i;
    }
    sort(niz,niz+a);

    for(ll i=0;i<a;++i)
    {
            if(mapa2[niz[i].first]==0)
            {
              V[pos1].push_back(make_pair(niz[i].first,niz[i].second));
              mapa2[niz[i].first]=pos1;
              mapa3[pos1]=niz[i].first;
              ++pos1;
            }
            else V[pos1].push_back(make_pair(niz[i].first,niz[i].second));
    }
    for(ll i=0;i<pos1;++i)
    {
            for(ll j=0;j<V[i].size();++j)
            {
                    if(j!=0)
                    {
                       if(euk>V[i][j].second-V[i][j-1].second)
                       {
                          euk=V[i][j].second-V[i][j-1].second;
                          toc=mapa[make_pair(mapa3[i],V[i][j].second)];
                          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[i][j-1].first,V[i][j-1].second)];
                       }
                    }
                    if(j!=V[i].size()-1)
                    {
                       //prllf("%d\n",V[i][j+1].second-V[i][j].second);
                       if(euk>V[i][j+1].second-V[i][j].second)
                       {
                          euk=V[i][j+1].second-V[i][j].second;
                          toc=mapa[make_pair(mapa3[i],V[i][j].second)];
                          toc2=mapa[make_pair(V[i][j+1].first,V[i][j+1].second)];
                       }
                    }
                    binary(i,j);
            }
    }
    printf("%llu %llu %.6lf\n",min(toc,toc2),max(toc,toc2),euk+ + 1e-9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not tell you what your bug is but I will tell you how to find it. Writing a brute force solution for small number of points is very easy-simply compute the distance between any two pairs and find the minimal of those distances. For small n this solution is good enough. Now generate random points(say up to 20) with relatively small coordinates(say up to 100) and compare the answers of your solution and the brute force. Keep on doing it until the answers of your solution and the brute force differs. When I tried this approach I found the cases where I was wrong really fast and the first moment I could not find a wrong test in 20 seconds, it turned out I have fixed my solution.

I solved a very similar problem about one week ago and I was able to fix my solution with exactly the approach I describe. Also I have done this during a running competition and I believe this is the correct approach to problems that may have many edge cases.

By the way the classical solution to this problem is using [divide and conquer](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=trcIU47nFqbmywPwjIGIDg&url=http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEdfa5KvVyPYDCLDEWMiegddHsgPw&sig2=5JAq_I53OLjaLVNWj_uUHQ) and this is the approach I implemented.

EDIT: actually after a little thought I think I can give an example that your solution you fail. Your logic is wrong - it may be the case that you need second to last x(or even further). Try this set of points: `(1, 1), (2,100), (3,2)`

Comment: Can you give me a little bit more information about D&C search for shortest pair.

Comment: I have implemented my solution using [this article](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=trcIU47nFqbmywPwjIGIDg&url=http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/ClosestPair.pdf&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEdfa5KvVyPYDCLDEWMiegddHsgPw&sig2=5JAq_I53OLjaLVNWj_uUHQ)